# Compreendendo código antigo JAVA

Tags: java, desempenho

Tenho um código aqui na empresa e preciso entender o que ele realmente faz.
Pela nomeclatura do método eu achei que ele removia os caracteres fora do padrão UTF-8 ou algo do tipo, dando uma analisada eu vi que ele não faz exatamente nada na string que passo.
Preciso que alguem me explique o que esse código realmente faz ou me de alguma dica sobre o mesmo para eu julgar se removo ou crio algo melhor.

```
public static String replaceUTF8(String text) {
    String[] REPLACES = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "c"};
    Pattern[] PATTERNS = new Pattern[REPLACES.length];
    PATTERNS[0] = Pattern.compile("[?????]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    PATTERNS[1] = Pattern.compile("[????]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    PATTERNS[2] = Pattern.compile("[????]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    PATTERNS[3] = Pattern.compile("[?????]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    PATTERNS[4] = Pattern.compile("[????]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    PATTERNS[5] = Pattern.compile("[?]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    String result = text;
    for (int i = 0; i < PATTERNS.length; i++) {
        Matcher matcher = PATTERNS[i].matcher(result);
        result = matcher.replaceAll(REPLACES[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

> OBS : É um código antigo e é utilizado em vários locais do sistema, preciso realmente entender o porque da existência e se não vai afetar caso eu o remova ou modifique.

Comment: Essas interrogações estão corretas? Não há sentido para algo assim.

Comment: Como o @GustavoCinque falou, não há sentido. Acredito que tinham as letras `áéíóúç` dentro desses regex e o programador decidiu ignorar esse método mudando simplesmente o regex para `?`. A única coisa que esse método faz é transformar o `?` em `a`, algo do tipo.

Comment: É exatamente isso, o código troca todos os `?`por `a` e n faz mais nada... Que coisa, não?

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, acho que foi realmente isso, o programador quando decidiu deixar o metodo de lado apenas colocou as interrogações, engraçado né ? o problema é que ele é chamado em todo o sistema = perca de desempenho